# Cannot compile my project with LINQ syntax

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have been using Entity Framework and now wanted to query with LINQ code. I assumed that my code would just compile if i copied it almost verbatim from my reference book "Entity Framework 4 In Action".

here is my code:

```
from a in db.addresses
where a.accountId == 1
Select o;
```

unexpectedly, intellisense did not accept any of my code. So I did a little research and added projects references, web.config assembly reference and using reference to LINQ

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

and have edited web.config to include

```
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Even Still, Intellisense and the compiled do not accept the keyword "in" or db.addresses (db is the context and elsewhere in my file i have no problem making calls like:

```
users currentUser = db.users.Single(m => m.email == User.Identity.Name);
```

so the problem is NOT my db context either. I've searched stack, asp.net, and googled "LINQ syntax not compiling" but can't find any further clue.

here are my compiler errors:

> Error 14 ; expected  147 20 AdamsStore
>
> Error 15 ; expected  147 23 AdamsStore
>
> Error 16 ; expected  148 23 AdamsStore
>
> Error 17 ; expected  148 39 AdamsStore
>
> Error 13 Invalid expression term 'in'  147 20 AdamsStore
>
> Error 8 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  147 18 AdamsStore
>
> Error 10 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  148 23 AdamsStore
>
> Error 7 The type or namespace name 'from' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  147 13 AdamsStore
>
> Error 11 The type or namespace name 'select' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  149 21 AdamsStore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `select` needs to be lowercase
2. You still need `using System.Linq` even if you have `using System.Data.Linq`

Comment: check, check, check. Already had reference and using for System.Linq. Meanwhile, I lower-cased Select to select and intellisense got even more upset. now nothing in my query is recognizable. Also have project ref to System.Core

Comment: @David, could you paste your compile errors (with the lowercase select) into your question?

Comment: I guess it is a mystery to everyone. I should not be so surprised, but I did not expect such a fundamental problem. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: the lower case DID work, but for some reason it took closing studio, reopening, cleaning the project, and re-building. Thanks @codesparkle! it was a silly error, but a noob like me never would have spotted it.